# If $\gcd(a, b) = p$, what are possible values of $\gcd(a^3, b^2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

> If $\gcd(a, b) = p$, where $p$ is a prime. Then what are possible values of $\gcd(a^3, b^2)$?

I have already calculated that $\gcd(a^2, b^2) = p^2$. $\gcd(a^2, b) = p$ or $p^2$, $\gcd(a^3, b) = p$ or $p^2$ or $p^3$. Can anybody give me any idea? how will I find the possible value of $\gcd(a^3, b^2)$?

Comment: In fact $p,p^2$ or $p^3$ do indeed exhaust all the possible values of $\text {gcd}\ (a^3,b).$

Comment: By similar reasoning you can find that $\text {gcd} \ (a^3,b^2) = p^2$ or $p^3.$

Comment: @Anacardium He asked "HOW" to find the solutions. He's asking for the logic behind it, the methodology, not blind solutions. He was quite explicit about that, in fact.  Please do be willing to educate rather than point game the site.  If youre quick to call people out for "homework cheating" in some questions, why hand out answers in others?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I don't want to give a blind solution. I don't have enough time in my hand to write down the complete solution. I will do it as soon as I find some time. If you want you can fill up the essential details needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is prime, each of $a$ and $b$ contain at least one factor of $p$, and one of them contains only one.

Case 1: If $b$ contains only one factor of $p$ regardless of how many factors of $p$ are contained in $a$, then $a^3$ contains at least $3$ factors, and $b^2$ contains only two factors of $p$, so $\gcd (a^3,b^2)=p^2$.

Case 2: If $a$ contains only one factor of $p$ and $b$ contains more than one factor of $p$, then $a^3$ contains $3$ factors of $p$, and $b^2$ contains at least $4$ factors of $p$, so $\gcd (a^3,b^2)=p^3$.